# What cannot have redundancy\high availability\failover in a server?

Tags: networking, security, backup, raid

I know some big companies such as IBM, Amazon, and governments require a high degree for availability and data retention with their servers. To achieve this they use redundancy. My question is, what components of a server (and cluster) are usually made redundant? I had briefly worked in such a server room and noticed redundancy in things such as

- power supplies
- RAID was used with minimum ~10 disks and usually had hot spare
- network cards
- the networks cards themselves had multiple Ethernet ports
- UPS backup
- diesel generator

What else is common to have in redundancy? I know an entire server could be mirrored. Can any computer component be made redundant, for example computers DO have multiple CPUs these days but I guess you wouldn't consider that redundant since they're all being used at once so the chance of failure is equivalent for all them, do I understand that correct? Can memory be made redundant?

I'd be interested in seeing statistics for which part of a server fails most frequently.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT copied your suggestion to title

Answer (score 2):

Any part of a server can be made redundant, but there can be significant tradeoffs which might be deal-breakers - depending on what you are doing -

The biggest one in many cases is redundant sites - even if you have 2 PC's if they are situated far from each other, latency can play havock with your IO.

Getting into the devices -

You can't really make memory redundant, but you can use ECC memory for added integrity.

You can't really have redundant motherboards - that really means 2 computers.

You can't really have redundant CPU's, although you can have multiple CPU's and disable one which does not perform.

The part of a computer to fail most often is the hard drive - by a long way.  Memory failures are also fairly common.

Comment: Why can't you have memory redundancy? Since memory is one of the more common things to fail (and when it does all operations may be lost) it would seem worthwhile as opposed to other things made redundant that don't fail as often, like the power supply. Some of the servers I saw had 4 redundant PS which seemed silly considering the failure point is more likely to be RAM or somewhere else.

Comment: ECC memory (error correcting memory) provides a level of redundancy, but that memory guards against bit flips, rather then the RAM dying.  I don't know how you would practically implement redundant memory.  I agree that a server with 4 redundant PS is overkill, but there is probably some logic to it - possibly to help with balancing a 3 phase supply, and having an 4th single phase supply in case the 3 phase dies altogether ?  Power supplies definitely do fail, but more importantly, power fails.  Having multiple PS's reduces the stress on a single PS as well.

Comment: Right, and I guess power supplies aren't hot swapable if one needs to be replaced.

Comment: Actually, server power supplies can be hot swappable - provided you have more then 1, and the remaining supply(s) can handle the load.